What is the reading being used for 辿
In the song 森の小さなレストラン, I can follow all but the opening lyrics.
The lyrics for the first line are given as どんぐりを辿っても but it sounds to me like Aoi Teshima is singing どんぐりをたたわっても or たたわても (gemination is heard to hear in lyrics, at least for me).  たたわても fits the meter (as best I can tell).
It doesn't sound like どんぐりをたどっても.
Am I just not hearing this correctly?  Or is this dialect?  Or, is this some kind of lyrical license?
My web searches aren't really pulling anything up that seems relevant.

Audio deciphering is off-topic.

@istrasci I wasn't actually asking to decipher the audio.  I was asking for an explanation for why the pronunciation wasn't what I expected.  As mentioned in the answer I accepted the sokuon is articulated differently in songs.  I merely linked to the audio so that my question might better be understood.

@istrasci As mentioned in my comments to the answer, I had already looked at the lyrics.  Accordingly, I knew what the proper deciphering of the lyrics was.  But, what was not clarified is why the transcription and what I heard differed.

Fair enough.  Retracted.

@KarlKnechtel Definitely related.  Thank you for linking to it.

It's たどっても. The sokuon (っ) is pronounced differently than in normal speech. The vowel from the previous mora (お) is extended. The result sounds like たどおても. This allows for a melody note to occur on the っ mora. This happens a lot in singing. Not always, but often.
Notice that melody notes also occur on ん (つきません, レストラン), and again on っ in からっぽ, which sounds like からあぽ, and ポケット, which becomes ポケエト.

Ah!  That makes sense.  Perfect.

The enunciation of ん is something that has ceased to cause problems.  I don't know when but at some point I stopped hearing ん like an "n" or "m" but as an entire beat of its own.  But, you point to other instances where I did find it difficult to hear what I expected  からっぽ and ポケット.  In fact, I had to look up the lyrics to understand some of what I was hearing, firstly with 辿っても and then with other items like からっぽ.
